# Tracking Prevention blocked access to storage for https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Space+Grotesk

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

I get this error in the console when i try to

```
@import url('https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Space+Grotesk');
```

in my CSS file. after a little research i found that it's a security setting in Microsoft edge but I couldn't find a way to solve it

I don't want to change my tracking settings and adding the URL to exceptions didn't work.

i tried to turn track prevention off and i got another error message

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Space+Grotesk with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
```

Comment: What are your tracking settings in Edge?

Comment: i am using balanced

Comment: Have you tried going down to Basic and using the site?

Comment: you might also want to look at this documentation on CORB: https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/corb-for-developers/

Comment: i did look at the provided website and went down with it it says in most cases it shouldn't affect behaviour but since it did i am supposed either change header of the request or send them a feedback the other option is to start chrome with this command  

--disable-features=CrossSiteDocumentBlockingAlways,CrossSiteDocumentBlockingIfIsolating

i don't know what side effects could this bring

Comment: Not the correct URL: `@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Space+Grotesk&display=swap');`

Comment: J, Titus that worked i actually had the url for the font family provided so didn't think it might be the problem it works even with strict track prevention settings